# HSQLDB on S3 Compatible Service

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, hsqldb

We use HSQLDB as a filesystem based database as our application requirements for a RDBMS is minimal. We would now like to move this application to Pivotal Cloud Foundry. S3 compatible storage (on cloud) is the only service compatible "filesystem" on physical machines.

So if we move our current HSQLDB to S3, we would not be able to make a direct JDBC connection to the HSQLDB "file" (as accessing S3 objects need authetication etc).

Has anyone faced such a situation before? Are there ways to access HSQLDB with S3 as a storage medium ?

Thanks,
Midhun

Answer (score 0):

Pivotal Cloud Foundry allows you to bind volume mounts to your `cf push`-ed applications. Thanks to the NFS volume service (see `cf marketplace -s`), you can bind volume mounts to your application with the usual `cf create-service` and `cf bind-service` commands. Then your HSQLDB files must be written under the filesystem directory where the NFS volume is mounted.

This could be handy a solution for running your app in Cloud Foundry with persistent filesystem storage for your HSQLDB database.

Default PCF installations provide such mount from some NFS server. Here is the [NFS volumes documentation](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-4/devguide/services/using-vol-services.html) and especially for your PCF operator, [how to enable this feature](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-4/opsguide/enable-vol-services.html).